# how to create custom entry in xamarin form ,as shown in following pic?

Tags: forms, xamarin

[image]

how to create custom entry with like this floating label in xamarin form.

Comment: Would this work https://alexdunn.org/2017/07/14/xamarin-control-xamarin-forms-materialentry/

Comment: but how to move placeholder to box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XF.Xamarin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XF.Material/) nuget to achieve similar Entry. This is under MIT licence. Make sure you go through licence before using any third party nugets in a production application.

Answer (score 0):

The [PhantomLib](https://github.com/OSTUSA/PhantomLib) library allows you to easily make a floating label in Xamarin.Forms, but does not have the border around it like in your picture. Maybe you don't need the border? Also MIT license.

Answer (score 0):

**Syncfusion** also have this type of control and please go through below link,

Link: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/text-input-layout/container-type